# Geoserver - Layered or Georeferenced PDF

Tags: geoserver, pdf

Has anyone had any experience with outputting maps from GeoServer into a Layered and / or Georeferenced PDF?

Answer (score 3):

This was also asked a few days ago on the GeoServer users mailing list http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Layered-PDF-documents-td5180147.html and one of the GeoServer main developers asked:

> Q: Is it possible to output the visible layers in GeoServer so each
>   layer is separated in the output PDF file?
>
> A: Not at the moment. But it would be really nice to have someone
>   implement this capability

There is also this open GeoServer issue:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-3640?jql=project%20%3D%20GEOS%20AND%20text%20~%20%22layers%20pdf%22

OpenJUMP PLUS can print to layered (not georeferenced) PDF with the SkyPrinter tool. I do  not know of any open source server program with that capability. It might be possible to configure MapServer for that with some special output template because GDAL can produce layered and georeferenced PDF files.